# How to override system default label forecolor in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, colors, label, default

Is it possible to change the "default" forecolor of a label?

I know I can change each control one-by-one in either design time or run time but I wonder if there is a better way.

I can do this at run time

```
lblCompanyName.ForeColor = color.darkblue
```

I could also have a loop to look at all of my controls on the form and change them in one small bit of code, but there must still be a better way.

I see at design time that the "default" label forecolor is "ControlText" so can I change ControlText perhaps to equal color.darkblue and then all of my labels will be dark blue without needing to code it one control at a time (or within a loop).

Thankyou
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it for a standard `Label` control but you can always create your own class that inherits `Label` and then sets the `ForeColor` property in the constructor.  You would then use that control instead of a `Label`.

EDIT:

If you want to change the text colour for all your `Label` controls at run time then you should use a bound application setting.  On the Settings page of the project properties, add a setting of type `Color` with User scope and name it `LabelForeColor` or something else if you prefer.  Now, select a `Label` in the designer, open the Properties window and use the (ApplicationSettings) -> (PropertyBindings) node to bind the `ForeColor` property to the setting you created.

You can then access that setting in code via `My.Settings.LabelForeColor` and any `Label` bound to it will be updated automatically.  You can bind as many different `Label` controls on as many different forms as you like.  You can only bind one at a time though, so I would recommend copying and pasting an existing bound `Label` rather than adding a new one each time.  If you have existing `Label` controls and you're confident enough, you can copy, paste and edit the binding code in the designer code file(s).

There's really no point your using a custom control in this case because the setting will control each control anyway.  No matter what value you set in the constructor, it will still be set by the bound setting afterwards.  Note that any change you make to a setting will be automatically saved at shutdown and reloaded at startup.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that and it works as you said so that helps me with my design time change. However, I was looking at being able to allow the user to change the colors to suit their preference and store that in a properties file and then change all the colors when the form loads. I can do that for all controls one-by-one in the code, but I was hoping I could be a bit smarter by just overriding the "defined" system keyword of ControlText and therefore all controls that refer to "ControlText" would automatically be updated.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your latest request.

Comment: Thank you so much @jmcilhinney. Creating an ApplicationSetting has worked EXACTLY how I want it to and gives me the control at runtime for the user to make their own colour choices. Thank you for taking the time to explain it as well as you did. I was able to solve this with your help in just a couple of minutes. :-)